# First match on one field only

Tags: sql, stimulsoft

I have a stimulsoft report where I want to pull the first asset record that is attached to a work order only. My datasource consists of three different joins, so I am trying to avoid using a sub select. I have tried using TOP, MIN and DISTINCT within the initial select statement but neither seem to work. Is there another method to achieve this?

Below is my query. The field we want to return the first match on is woa.AssetID

```
select 
wo.[EndDate],
wo.[WorkOrderID],
wo.[ID],
woa.[AssetID],
trm.*
from 
[reports].[WorkOrders] wo
Left Join [reports].[InventoryTransactions] invt On wo.[ID]=invt.[WorkOrderID]  
Left Join [reports].[WorkOrderAssets] woa On woa.[ID]=wo.[ID]
Join [reports].[WorkOrderForm_TrafficLightingRepairMaintenance] trm On trm.ID = wo.ID 
where
wo.[DepartmentName]='TPW Traffic' 
and wo.[StatusName]='Closed' 
and ((invt.[Name] like '%LED%' OR invt.[Name] like '%led%') 
and (invt.[Name] like '%Head%' OR invt.[Name] like '%head%' 
OR invt.[Name] like '%LAMP%' OR invt.[Name] like '%lamp%'))
and (cast(wo.[EndDate] as date) between @from and @to)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are getting too many rows because of the join to WorkOrderAssets and you would like that join to return at most one asset row (just the first one).

One of the best ways to solve this is by using a windowing function on the table that is returning more rows than you want. I don't know what database you are using, but for SQL Server, the amended query would look like this:

```
select
wo.[EndDate],
wo.[WorkOrderID],
wo.[ID],
woa.[AssetID],
trm.*
from 
[reports].[WorkOrders] wo
Left Join [reports].[InventoryTransactions] invt On wo.[ID]=invt.[WorkOrderID]  

Left Join 
    (select
        [ID],
        [AssetID],
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by AssetID) as RowNumber
    from [reports].[WorkOrderAssets] 
    ) woa On woa.[ID]=wo.[ID] and RowNumber = 1

Join [reports].[WorkOrderForm_TrafficLightingRepairMaintenance] trm On trm.ID = wo.ID 
where
wo.[DepartmentName]='TPW Traffic' 
and wo.[StatusName]='Closed' 
and ((invt.[Name] like '%LED%' OR invt.[Name] like '%led%') 
and (invt.[Name] like '%Head%' OR invt.[Name] like '%head%' 
OR invt.[Name] like '%LAMP%' OR invt.[Name] like '%lamp%'))
and (cast(wo.[EndDate] as date) between @from and @to)
```